# How to zoom in Firefox-geckodriver by selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

Tried using Python
Option with `document.body.style.zoom= '150%'`, not suitable.
And with `document.body.style.zoom= '1.5'` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry I almost immediately found a solution after the post of the question)

`webdriver.execute_script("document.body.style.MozTransform='scale(1)';")`